# Need to deploy a react web app integrated with rasa model

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, chatbot, rasa

I followed this tutorial "https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-a-weather-chatbot-b8ef1b1d6703". Now, I was wondering how can I deploy this react interface with the rasa model on the web.

I have a react chatbot user interface that is running my rasa model. I have to start my rasa server on my local machine and then I have to start my react app server to run the chatbot.
I know how to deploy a react web app.
I need to know how can I deploy this application(both rasa model and react web app)
Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need one server for your React App, and the second one for the Rasa server. After that, you will be able to call your Rasa Server.
So try to use the Rasa Heroku setup template for your backend.

Also if You will want to use rasa custom actions, you will need to create a separate server for this purpose and connect the NLU server and Action server through action_endpoint on NLU side.